# Contact Form Not Working after hosting Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I know this question that had been asked before but didn't find an appropriate solution to it yet! I hosted my website a few days ago. Everything works normally in my website a part of my contact form that it doesn't work! 
The contact form itself doesn't show any errors whatsoever, in fact when I send the details I still get the label message that confirms of sending process, but nothing comes into my email. 
The strange thing is when I talked to my host provider, he says to me that there is nothing wrong with my script and they didn't block any port.

I also ran the contact page and done the same process by filling all required fields and it works properly.Any help would much appreciated!
My code :

```
 namespace contact
 {
   public partial class ContactUs : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new 
          ScriptResourceDefinition
        {
            Path = "~/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"
        });

     }

     protected void btnSub_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        try
        {

                if (Page.IsValid)
                {
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    mail.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
                    mail.To.Add("myemailaddress");
                    mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
                    mail.Body = "<b> Sender Name: </b>" + txtName.Text + "  
                 <br/>"
                        + "<b> Sender Email: </b>" + txtEmail.Text + "<br/>"
                        + "<b> Sender Comment: </b>" + txtMessage.Text;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient smtpClient = new
            SmtpClient("company's mail", 587);
                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtpClient.Credentials = new

          System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemailaddress","password");
          smtpClient.Send(mail);

                    lblmsg.Text = "Thank  you for contacting us";

                    txtName.Enabled = false;
                    txtEmail.Enabled = false;
                    txtSubject.Enabled = false;
                    txtMessage.Enabled = false;
                    btnSub.Enabled = false;

                }

         }

         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            lblmsg.Text = "An unexpected error has occured! " + ex.Message;
         }
      }

  }
```

Comment: Check your spam folder. Also, have your provider check the SMTP logs to see if there was a problem delivering the message.

Comment: I checked the spam and there is nothing in there!